# How can I improve my critical rating in Wizard101 at a low level?

Tags: wizard101

So, I have been playing Wizard101 for about a week now, and I am hooked. The only problem is that I have been wondering, how do I improve my critical rate at level 20. I am a balance wizard, and I have just made it to the Krokosphinx in Krokotopia.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to get critical at your level which is winterbane, the robe for level 10 gives a 4 critical rating or 1% chance. Idk if it gives bettter for level 20 though but I am level 40 hope I have helped. P.S. I have gotten to level 20 non member.

Also, at level 20 one of winterbane's robes give 5 critical

Answer (score 0):

you won't have critical unless you have certain gear, critical was introduced to the game when celestia was released which was lvl 50-60, so until later on you won't have any gear that raises critical